# Extract Date Along with Am or pm in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-substr

I want to get the time pattern along with AM or PM from the given string `Aaaaa_gggg_ne_A030_66788_Abcd_Oct_24_0329PM.csv`

I tried the following:

```
Select regexp_substr(filename,'\d{4}',1,3)
From
(Select 'Aaaaa_gggg_ne_A030_66788_Abcd_Oct_24_0329PM.csv' filename from dual);
```

which only gives me the last number, e.g. `0329`, but I need `0329PM`.

Answer (score 2):

Using this form of REGEXP_SUBSTR() will get what you need in one call.  It returns the first group, which is the set of characters after the last underscore and before the literal period of 1 or more numbers followed by an A or P then an M.

```
with tbl(filename) as (
  Select 'Aaaaa_gggg_ne_A030_66788_Abcd_Oct_24_0329PM.csv'  
  from dual
)
select regexp_substr(filename, '_(\d+[AP]M)\.', 1, 1, NULL, 1) 
From tbl;
```

Actually, to tighten up the match you could make it case-insensitive and add the extension:

```
select regexp_substr(filename, '_(\d+[AP]M)\.csv', 1, 1, 'i', 1) 
From tbl;
```

Note if a match is not found NULL will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Nested `substr` is one option (if data *always* looks like this; you didn't say it doesn't):

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Aaaaa_gggg_ne_A030_66788_Abcd_Oct_24_0329PM.csv' from dual)
  3  select substr(substr(col, -10), 1, 6) result from test
  4  /

RESULT
------
0329PM

SQL>
```

- the inner `substr` returns the last 10 characters (`0329PM.csv`)
- the outer `substr` returns the first 6 characters out of it (`0329PM`)

---

Or, using regular expressions:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Aaaaa_gggg_ne_A030_66788_Abcd_Oct_24_0329PM.csv' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(translate(col, '_.', '  '), '\S+',
  4                       1,
  5                       regexp_count(translate(col, '_.', '  '), '\S+') - 1
  6                      ) result
  7  from test;

RESULT
------
0329PM

SQL>
```

- line #3: `translate` replaces underlines and dots with a space
- line #4: start from the beginning
- line #5: return substring which is *one before the last one*